# lazy loading effect doesn't seems to work on my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading

someone have a an idea about lazy loading. It doesn't seems to work on my page.

I did something wrong ?

here is my page -> http://500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/test.html

here is my html part:

```
<img class="lazy img-responsive" src="...jpg" data-original="...jpg" alt=""/>
```

here is my js part:

```
$(function() {
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
effect : "fadeIn"
});
```

here is my jquery.lazyload.js page:

```
 /*!
  * Lazy Load - jQuery plugin for lazy loading images
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2007-2015 Mika Tuupola
  *
  * Licensed under the MIT license:
  *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  *
  * Project home:
  *   http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
  *
  * Version:  1.9.5
  *
 */

 (function($, window, document, undefined) {
var $window = $(window);

$.fn.lazyload = function(options) {
    var elements = this;
    var $container;
    var settings = {
        threshold       : 0,
        failure_limit   : 0,
        event           : "scroll",
        effect          : "show",
        container       : window,
        data_attribute  : "original",
        skip_invisible  : false,
        appear          : null,
        load            : null,
        placeholder     : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
    };

    function update() {
        var counter = 0;

        elements.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (settings.skip_invisible && !$this.is(":visible")) {
                return;
            }
            if ($.abovethetop(this, settings) ||
                $.leftofbegin(this, settings)) {
                    /* Nothing. */
            } else if (!$.belowthefold(this, settings) &&
                !$.rightoffold(this, settings)) {
                    $this.trigger("appear");
                    /* if we found an image we'll load, reset the counter */
                    counter = 0;
            } else {
                if (++counter > settings.failure_limit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    if(options) {
        /* Maintain BC for a couple of versions. */
        if (undefined !== options.failurelimit) {
            options.failure_limit = options.failurelimit;
            delete options.failurelimit;
        }
        if (undefined !== options.effectspeed) {
            options.effect_speed = options.effectspeed;
            delete options.effectspeed;
        }

        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    /* Cache container as jQuery as object. */
    $container = (settings.container === undefined ||
                  settings.container === window) ? $window : $(settings.container);

    /* Fire one scroll event per scroll. Not one scroll event per image. */
    if (0 === settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
        $container.bind(settings.event, function() {
            return update();
        });
    }

    this.each(function() {
        var self = this;
        var $self = $(self);

        self.loaded = false;

        /* If no src attribute given use data:uri. */
        if ($self.attr("src") === undefined || $self.attr("src") === false) {
            if ($self.is("img")) {
                $self.attr("src", settings.placeholder);
            }
        }

        /* When appear is triggered load original image. */
        $self.one("appear", function() {
            if (!this.loaded) {
                if (settings.appear) {
                    var elements_left = elements.length;
                    settings.appear.call(self, elements_left, settings);
                }
                $("<img />")
                    .bind("load", function() {

                        var original = $self.attr("data-" + settings.data_attribute);
                        $self.hide();
                        if ($self.is("img")) {
                            $self.attr("src", original);
                        } else {
                            $self.css("background-image", "url('" + original + "')");
                        }
                        $self[settings.effect](settings.effect_speed);

                        self.loaded = true;

                        /* Remove image from array so it is not looped next time. */
                        var temp = $.grep(elements, function(element) {
                            return !element.loaded;
                        });
                        elements = $(temp);

                        if (settings.load) {
                            var elements_left = elements.length;
                            settings.load.call(self, elements_left, settings);
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("src", $self.attr("data-" + settings.data_attribute));
            }
        });

        /* When wanted event is triggered load original image */
        /* by triggering appear.                              */
        if (0 !== settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
            $self.bind(settings.event, function() {
                if (!self.loaded) {
                    $self.trigger("appear");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    /* Check if something appears when window is resized. */
    $window.bind("resize", function() {
        update();
    });

    /* With IOS5 force loading images when navigating with back button. */
    /* Non optimal workaround. */
    if ((/(?:iphone|ipod|ipad).*os 5/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
        $window.bind("pageshow", function(event) {
            if (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.persisted) {
                elements.each(function() {
                    $(this).trigger("appear");
                });
            }
        });
    }

    /* Force initial check if images should appear. */
    $(document).ready(function() {
        update();
    });

    return this;
};

/* Convenience methods in jQuery namespace.           */
/* Use as  $.belowthefold(element, {threshold : 100, container : window}) */

$.belowthefold = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = (window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $window.height()) + $window.scrollTop();
    } else {
        fold = $(settings.container).offset().top + $(settings.container).height();
    }

    return fold <= $(element).offset().top - settings.threshold;
};

$.rightoffold = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = $window.width() + $window.scrollLeft();
    } else {
        fold = $(settings.container).offset().left + $(settings.container).width();
    }

    return fold <= $(element).offset().left - settings.threshold;
};

$.abovethetop = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = $window.scrollTop();
    } else {
        fold = $(settings.container).offset().top;
    }

    return fold >= $(element).offset().top + settings.threshold  + $(element).height();
};

$.leftofbegin = function(element, settings) {
    var fold;

    if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
        fold = $window.scrollLeft();
    } else {
        fold = $(settings.container).offset().left;
    }

    return fold >= $(element).offset().left + settings.threshold + $(element).width();
};

$.inviewport = function(element, settings) {
     return !$.rightoffold(element, settings) && !$.leftofbegin(element, settings) &&
            !$.belowthefold(element, settings) && !$.abovethetop(element, settings);
 };

/* Custom selectors for your convenience.   */
/* Use as $("img:below-the-fold").something() or */
/* $("img").filter(":below-the-fold").something() which is faster */

$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "below-the-fold" : function(a) { return $.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "above-the-top"  : function(a) { return !$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "right-of-screen": function(a) { return $.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "left-of-screen" : function(a) { return !$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "in-viewport"    : function(a) { return $.inviewport(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    /* Maintain BC for couple of versions. */
    "above-the-fold" : function(a) { return !$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "right-of-fold"  : function(a) { return $.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
    "left-of-fold"   : function(a) { return !$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); }
});

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I would recommend not to use an img tag as placeholder. The src attribute is [mandatory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) and so you generate invalid HTML.
- And I also [wouldn't use jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) for such a tiny functionality.

The following [justlazy plugin](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/) provides valid HTML without jQuery.

**1.** Define a placeholder

```html
<span data-src="default/image" data-alt="some alt text"
      class="justlazy-placeholder">
</span>
```

**2.** Register lazy loading

```js
$(function() {
    Justlazy.registerLazyLoadByClass("justlazy-placeholder");
});
```

Comment: I've forgotten to add the library link ;) Is added now

Answer (score 0):

**First Issue:**

You need to close down the ready function.

```
$(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect : "fadeIn"
    });
});
```

**Second Issue:**

Here is the usage on how to implement the lazy load on the site:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```

Now with this you have to store it within a data attribute (the image itself). What you are doing is calling the image within the src and also within the data attribute. Now when the page loads, it actually starts the process of loading the images with src and then the lazy load happens.

Comment: when you try, does it works, i think nothing change ?

Comment: @fatyfatoumata edited my post. If you would like a live example to edit, please use codepen or jsfiddle and use online resources e.g. lazyload cdn and placehold.it images